# use CSS grid with dc-js?

Tags: css, css-grid, dc.js

I have been trying to use CSS grid layout with `dc-js`.

The graphs are defined without specifying a height and a width, letting the grid do its theoretical job.

I end up with something like the following image, where the graph ends up occupying only a third of the lateral space I had set for it in the grid layout. The `svg` within each individual graph's `div` still has default height and width set for some reason.

Is that the expected behaviour ?

If it isn't how do I solve this issue ?

EDIT : of course it works in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chapo/1fsyhwn9/)... I'm using dc version 3.0.12 if that helps.

[image]

Comment: Why is the output different than in the image? https://nimb.ws/8UysFZ

Comment: Yes I can't replicate it in the fiddle...

Comment: Then send the page where it is showing your wrong output. Otherwise, how can we help?

Comment: yes fully aware of that. was hoping someone had encountered the same issue and would have been able to help without the actual code. It's just too complicated to even attempt to replicate the actual page itself.

Comment: will give it a try nonetheless but happy to get ideas anyway

Comment: It looks like perhaps the title (or is that a button?) and some other invisible element are taking up the other 2/3 of each grid cell. Have you tried putting nothing but the chart into each div? I agree this is pretty hard to debug without seeing the actual code for the wrong result.

Comment: Ah no that's just Firefox highlighting the named grid spaces defined in my css file. Each graph is alone in its own div.

Comment: @Gordon ok got the default 200*200 size. Why would the default size still be applied even though I'm using CSS grid ? Does it always have precedence over calculated height and width ? In my charts definition, I do not give a width and height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resizing and setting the width and height of a chart based on its container are not completely automatic in dc.js.

As you discovered, the default width and height are 200. But you can cause the chart to calculate either one by passing a non-number such as `null`.

This is partly for historical reasons and partly to provide more control. dc.js didn't have these features early on, and we usually try to add features in a backward-compatible way.

If your grid changes size when the window changes size, you can add an `onresize` listener that causes every chart to resize the SVG to the same size as the chart div:

```
window.onresize = function() {
    [chart1,chart2,chart3,chart4].forEach(
    c => {
      c.width(null).height(null).rescale();
      redraw_chart_no_transitions(c);
    });
};
```

If `onresize` is not to your taste, take a look at the [resize observer  scatter example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/resizing/resizing-scatter-flexbox-observer.html) for a more modern approach. You may need a resize observer if the grid will resize for another reason than window resize.

`redraw_chart_no_transitions` is a small utility function [available here](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/resizing/dc-restore-transition-duration.js) that temporarily sets `transitionDuration` to zero so that redraw does not animate. Animated transitions are not good for actions that give immediate feedback like resize, pan, and zoom.

I was able to reproduce the problem pictured in your question with your fiddle by making the window really large.

To get the grid layout to use all the space I added the following CSS (not perfect, there's some stuff I don't understand here):

```
html, body {
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  margin: 1em;
}

#test {
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  /* ... */
}
```

By default grid cells can get larger but not smaller. Specify `min-width: 0` and `min-height: 0` to allow them to get smaller:

```
#test div {
  min-width: 0; min-height: 0;
}
```

Here is a [fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/y2f3j96h/107/) with four charts that fill the window and resize when the window is resized.

[image: chart grid screenshot]

Comment: Great ! Thank you very much for your detailed answer. That's even better than what I had in mind. Didn't even think about resizing in my question. Just getting the graphs to show up the first time at the right size would have been good enough. Will play around with your stuff and validate the answer.

Comment: ok it doesn't work for me in real life because forcing tyhe recalculation through `c.width(null).height(null).rescale();` (within my `preRedraw` and `preRender`) actually resets the size to the default. Do you know off hand where the size is actually calculated in dc.js codebase so I can see why it comes up with the default in my case ?

Comment: That should work - [example with dc@3 and preRedraw/preRender](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/ycae7k84/15/). Check the width/height accessor on the base mixin and see if `_defaultWidthCalc` / `_defaultHeightCalc` are getting hit.

Comment: so `var width = element && element.getBoundingClientRect && element.getBoundingClientRect().width;` at line 24 of the `base-mixin` (or line 1416 of `dc.js`) returns 0 for all my charts. Is that meant to happen ?

Comment: I figured it out but it has no place in the answer... It's because initlaly, my grid was on a jquery tab which was hidden, hence not returning the correct boudingclientrect info. Will add it as an answer but still validate yours .

Answer (score 1):

Posting this answer for any lost souls finding this question.

In my specific case, my grid was on a JQuery tab which was hidden on initialization of the dc graphs.

`var width = element && element.getBoundingClientRect && element.getBoundingClientRect().width;` at line 24 of the base-mixin (or line 1416 of dc.js) returned 0 for all my charts.

So dc could not calculate the correct sizes and ended up using default for everything.

Once I solved that, @Gordon's answer helped me for resizing.

Comment: Argh, yes, getting the size of something that is hidden can often cause problems. I've seen similar problems when a tab (window) is loaded in the background too. Thanks for following up!